# Writing output in same txt files in main program from subroutines in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have written a code including 6 subroutines firstly I have written outputs in main program and I got correct text files but now I also want to add one variable's output from another subroutine in the same text file here is my code example

```
 ! code for the particle tracing in magnetic field    
      implicit none
      include "mydata.inc"
      External ad,bsstep
      real*8 x(ndim,nv),b(4)

      real*8 pwE(ndim,3),pwB(ndim,3),ep

      real*8 ke,gamma,kew,epx,hmin,rr,epx0
      real*8 eps(3),eta0(5)
      real*8 m,d_eta
      real*8 t,tw,dt,rt
      integer i,j,k,nok,nbad,filen
      character*80 fname1
 !     real,parameter :: pi

      t=0.d0
      tw=0.d0
      m=me
      x=0.d0
      pwE=0.d0
      pwB=0.d0

 !     

      !=====loop================!
      k=1
 120  call ini_v(x,ke,pwB)
      x(2,3)=eta0(k)
      call dispersion(pwE,pwB,eps,ep)

      write(fname1,1005) k

      open(1,file=fname1)

      write(1,*)'time,eta,phi,pitch angle,ke,deta'

      !====normalization========!
      ke=ke/(m*c**2)
      gamma=ke+1
      x(1,2)=cos(alpha)*dsqrt(ke**2+2*ke)
      x(2,2)=sin(alpha)*dsqrt(ke**2+2*ke)
      dt=0.001

      epx=1.d-6       ! required accuracy
    epx0=epx
    hmin=0.d0
      !================================

      rt=0
      kew=ke*(m*c**2)/1.0d6/e !ke in the units of electron volts

 100  write(*,*)rt
      if(rt.gt.15)then
          goto 110
      endif
      if(rt.eq.0)then
      write(1,1000)t/(2*pi),
     &(x(i,3),i=1,2),alpha*180.d0/pi,kew,d_eta

      else
      write(1,1000)t/(2*pi),
     &(x(i,3),i=1,2),alpha*180.d0/pi,kew,d_eta
      endif

      !=========adaptivestepsize method==============!

      call odeint(x,t,t+dt,epx,dt,hmin,nok,nbad,ad,bsstep,
     &pwE,pwB,gamma,ep)

      x(1:2,3)=mod(x(1:2,3),2*pi) !this is the range of angles
      alpha=dacos(x(1,2)/dsqrt(x(1,2)**2+x(2,2)**2))
      call go(KE,x(1:2,2),gamma)
      KEw=KE*(m*c**2)/1.0d6/e
      t=t+dt
      rt=rt+dt
      goto 100

 110  write(*,*) eta0(k)

      if(k.le.size(eta0)) then
          k=k+1
          t=0
          goto 120

      endif 

 1000 format(6(E10.4,2x),4(f15.6,2x))
 1005  format("output",i2.2,".txt")     


      stop
      end
```

and the subroutine from where I want to get value is this

=============================================

```
! subroutine to calculate all the derivatives for this code
      subroutine ad(step,kin,kout,pwE,pwB,gamma,ep)
      include "mydata.inc"
      real*8 step
      real*8 kin(ndim,nv),kout(ndim,nv)
      real*8 pwE(ndim,3),pwB(ndim,3),ep
      real*8 gamma
      real*8 tm(3)







      kout(1,1)=kin(2,2)*cos(kin(2,3)-kin(1,3))/gamma
      kout(2,1)=kin(2,2)*sin(kin(2,3)-kin(1,3))/gamma
      kout(3,1)=kin(1,2)/gamma



      kout(1,2)=-pwE(3,1)*sin(kin(1,3))
     &+(pwB(1,1)*kin(2,2)/(2.*gamma))
     &*((1+ep)*sin(kin(2,3))+(1-ep)*sin(kin(2,3)-2*kin(1,3)))

      tm(1)=-pwB(1,1)*kin(1,2)/2./gamma
      tm(2)=pwB(1,1)*emicwave/wavek/cos(si)
      tm(3)=tan(si)*pwE(3,1)

      kout(2,2)=sin(kin(2,3))*(tm(1)*(1+ep)+1./2.*((1+ep)*tm(2)-tm(3)))
     &+sin(kin(2,3)-2*kin(1,3))
     &*(tm(1)*(1-ep)+1./2.*((1-ep)*tm(2)+tm(3))) 



      kout(1,3)=EMICwave-kin(1,2)*wavek*cos(si)/gamma
     &-kin(2,2)*wavek*sin(si)*cos(kin(2,3)-kin(1,3))/gamma

!----------------------d(eta)/dt --------------------------!
!     kin(2,3)=eta, kout(2,3)=d(eta)/dt
!   time derivatives of phase(phi)
!----------------------------------------------------------!

      tm(1)=-2*tm(1)
      kout(2,3)=EMICwave-kin(1,2)*wavek*cos(si)/gamma
     &-kin(2,2)*wavek*sin(si)*cos(kin(2,3)-kin(1,3))/gamma
     &+1./gamma-cos(kin(2,3))/(2.*kin(2,2))
     &*((1+ep)*tm(1)-(1+ep)*tm(2)+tm(3))
     &-cos(kin(2,3)-2*kin(1,3))/(2.*kin(2,2))
     &*((1-ep)*tm(1)-(1-ep)*tm(2)-tm(3))
     &-pwB(3,1)/gamma*cos(kin(1,3))



    return
    end
```

Comment: Welcome please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions and use the appropriate formatting for your code (see the edits I did).

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is the output wrong? Is there any error message? See also [ask]. Note that we cannot test your code because we do not have the include file. Also, your subroutine is missing `implicit none`.

Comment: I want to get the values from the subroutine and how can I send you the include file will u give me the emial?

Comment: You should not send anything to anyone. You should [edit] your question and include all relevant information. Please be sure to clearly *explain your problem*. Be specific. I do not understand your problem at all. Are there any error messages? What exactly did you try? What happened?

Comment: Unit numbers are global.  If you have `write(1,1000)` in the main program, then you can do `write(1,XXXX)` in the subroutine.  Here, `XXXX` is an appropriate format or format label.  BTW, it is often suggested to use unit numbers that start at 10.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: I'd stay away from file units of less than 10 -- you will never know whether your compiler just happens to use that particular number for things like standard out or similar (most use unit 0 for standard error, and 5 and 6 for standard in and standard out, but there's no guarantee).

The safest way is to use the `newunit` argument during open:

```
 integer :: unt

 open(newunit=unt, file=filename)

 write(unt, *) "Some text"

 close(unt)
```

If the file is open when the subroutine is called, then the subroutine should in theory only need that file unit to write output to that file (assuming that the subroutine is not `pure`).

If you want to, you can pass the file i/o to a module that you then `use` in both your main program and your subroutine.